# Set $pageName globally in pagination Laravel

Tags: laravel

We can use a custom **$customPageName** in laravel's **paginate()** function's 3rd parameter.By that we can use site.com/url?**$customPageName**=n . Is there any way we can set the custom page name globally ? In AppServiceProvider or somewhere like that?So we don't need to define every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solution. I give you two that IMO are the best:

#### 1: Create a trait and use it in every component

I love to use traits, they avoid a lot of redundancy and can be easily invoked everywhere:

```php
trait PaginationTrait
{
    const PAGE_NAME = 'your_global_value'

    public function paginate($query, $perPage, $columns = [''], $page_name = null)
    {
        return $query->paginate($perPage, $columns, $page_name ?: self::PAGE_NAME);
    }
}
```

This solution requires anyway that you pass as input a Builder instance, and may cause a logic problem. So let's move to the next solution

#### 2: Config files

Simply set a variable in an existing config file or in a new config file:

```php
// Example: app.php

return [
    // [...]

    'page_name' => 'your_custom_value' // or env('APP_PAGE_NAME', 'your_custom_value'),

    // [...]
];
```

And in your controller you can retrive the value as follows:

```php
    public function index() {
         // [...]

         $result = MyModel::paginate($per_page, $columns, config('app.page_name'));
    }
```

#### 3: App\Http\Controllers\Controller

The third solution is the easiest. Set a constant in your `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class (as I wrote for the trait part) and by the OOP rules, it will be inherited to all your controllers:

```php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    const PAGE_NAME = 'your_global_value';
}
```

And in your controller:

```php
    public function index() {
         // [...]

         $result = MyModel::paginate($per_page, $columns, self::PAGE_NAME);
    }
```

In my opinion, if you simply have to set this global variable, solution **2** and **3** are the best... If you have to create a custom pagination logic, then I think that creating a specific Trait or Class is a good choice

Comment: Fot me solution 1 is the best.I'm using service repository pattern .So i just need to set a wrapper in the base repository.Thank you for your solution

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you think that my answer is correct, feel free to accept it